# All options greyed out when trying to configure Active Directory Domain Services Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I am configuring the first domain controller for a new domain.  The install of Active Directory Domain Services seemed to go ok, but when I attempt to configure the domain controller it gets stuck on the second step "Domain Controller Options".  No error message pops up, it just looks like the window is loading and all the options to click on things such as the drop down for Forest Functional Level or the Next button are greyed out.  The only thing I can click on is Cancel.  Its been sitting at this stage for 20+ minutes.  [Screen shot of step that it is stuck on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVDj8.png)  Any thoughts as to what may be happening and how I can correct it?  The only roles installed are AD DS, DHCP, DNS.  DHCP and DNS have not yet been configured and AD DS is where I'm running into issues.

Thank You!

Comment: As I see all stuff is greyed out because of processing (animated blue bar on the top).

Answer (score 1):

Able to solve this issue by opening the services.msc and starting "DS Role Server" service. It was on manual start mode, made it automatic for further boot ups.